# invalid regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to regular expressions. I wrote a pattern like below:

```
'A/[.]+;'.'B/[.0-9]+;'.'C/[0-9]+;'.'D/[.]+;'.'E/[.0-9]+;'.'F/[.a-zA-Z]+;';
```

which is meant to match strings such as

> "A/U88;B/12.01.5;C/123456;D/4ND8;E/3.56.78;F/Sa.yA;"

But I got an error invalid Regular Expression.

What's wrong about this pattern?

Comment: Edit your question, it's unclear. It's difficult to say where starts your pattern, your string or whatever, and how you use it. Take the time to write a clear question without any ambiguity.

Comment: You need to show us the exact error message. (copy/paste it). You probably also need to wrap your regex in some [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is not in good format. Amongst other erorrs you are not escaping the special character `/` properly.

To escape special characters in a regex expression use the `\` as a preceeding character. So to escape the `/` character you would have to write `\/`.

---

In order to obtain the characters between each `/ ;` pair from the string:

```
$string = 'A/U88;B/12.01.5;C/123456;D/4ND8;E/3.56.78;F/Sa.yA;'
```

you can use `preg_match_all()`.

> **`preg_match_all`** — Perform a global regular expression match

and set the flag `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER`.

> **`PREG_PATTERN_ORDER`** Orders results so that $matches[0] is an array of full pattern matches, $matches[1] is an array of strings matched by the first parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Now you can access the `$matches[1]` array which are the characters that matched the regular expression inside the parentheses `()`.

more on `preg_match_all()`: [php.net/preg-match-all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

---

**Here is a working example:**

```
$string = 'A/U88;B/12.01.5;C/123456;D/4ND8;E/3.56.78;F/Sa.yA;';

// [A-F] accepts one upper case character from A-F
// [0-9]? accepts one number from 0-9, the ? means the number may or may not exist there
// ([^;]+) accepts one or more of any characters except semicolons
preg_match_all('/[A-F][0-9]?\/([^;]+);/', $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

which outputs:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => U88 
        [1] => 12.01.5 
        [2] => 123456 
        [3] => 4ND8 
        [4] => 3.56.78 
        [5] => Sa.yA
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what that string mean or what you are trying to do, but your regex did have some synthax error in it. First of all, you need to escape the `/`. Second, I couldn't make it work, so I built one that matches your stirng. I don't know if the order of the letter is important or not.
`[ABCDEF](\/)([A-Z0-9.]+);`

Here is a working Regex101 with your regex.
https://regex101.com/r/jXUqav/1

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's very helpful! basically I'm trying to parse a string and get the useful information after each "/". There are some contexts: (1) The order of ABCDEF doesn't matter, and (2) some strings may not have all ABCDEF fields (for example they may only have A and B). (3) If I replace each of ABCDEF with multiple characters such as A -> A5, how should I write the expression?

Comment: If you know that the slash is always dividing the elements of a string, the explode() command is the most versatile way to get an arbitrary number of elements

Comment: @user284602 After reading your comment I edited to give you what I think is the proper answer. Next time consider including all the details in your question. I didn't know that you wanted only the characters between the `/` and `;`, from your question above it seems you wanted to match the whole string. I also added the possibility for the letters A,B, C.. to contain numbers, but they don't have to. The question mark `?` in the regex makes the presence of a number (after a letter A-F) optional. Peace